# My CodeIgniter model doesn't work only on this page

Tags: php, codeigniter

thanks to help me.

In CodeIgniter, I have a Controller named "Idee" in which there is this function :

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->model("idee");
    echo "Doesn t go ahead";
    $data['idees'] = $this->idee->getAll();
    var_dump($data);
    $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
}
```

But when I try the URL, the page is blank, and even the echo is not reached.

It is weir because I already did this on others page, and it's working.

Could you help me please ? Thanls a lot !

Comment: Since your method works in one place, there's obviously nothing wrong with the method itself. You need to post the surrounding and calling code for us to give proper advice. My initial idea, though, would be that you're not loading the model, but this should give you an error. Remember to enable error reporting both in PHP and CodeIgniter.

Comment: Well I got exactly the same code in my Home.php which is the main Controller

Comment: I've checked hours, and nothing goes wrong in the code. Did you already have a thing like that ? Moreover, I thnik it's just a little error, but I actually don't know where it can come.

Comment: Are you saying that your two Controller files are absolutely identical?

Comment: Yes, but, it's just to test and trying to understand why it work on a page, and not on the other ... :)

Comment: You need to put some debugging code in your model getAll() function because it would appear that is where it is failing. Please post your getAll function from the model.

Comment: Try loading the model in constructor. And turn the developement mode on for error reporting.

Comment: @davidethell The `getAll()` method is not invoked until after the echo has occurred, so the executing doesn't even reach that method.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for your answer, but I found the response. I called my Model with the same name as my Controller.

Comment: Excuse me, please, and again thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 2):

You need to name your model something different from your controller. It is failing because you are trying to redeclare the same class (Idee). Usually in CodeIgniter you would call your model something like Idee_m (the file and class).